# Multiple pressing the switch buttons in PIC16F877

Tags: assembly, pic

I work on PIC16F877

I want to clear one thing. There is the configuration of our board:

[image: Picture]

It is homework, so you must not help me, only hints :). So the task says that I must push **SW00** button for start, and later push **SW04**, **SW05**, **SW06**, **SW07** for calibration of number in the LEDs, and then finish by pressing **SW11**. Two things worry me:

1. How to check if button is pressed because I only check RB4,RB5,RB6,RB7 bits, so I can't distinguish for example SW00 and SW04 buttons(RB4). And also it is said that:"In your development boards RB4 pin is connected to RC2 pin. Therefore you have to  configure RB4 and RC2 properly for correct operation of buttons."
2. These buttons are not Schmidt-triggered, so I can use TIMER0, can you light up about this stuff.

With regards!!

Comment: Consider: What happens if you turn off RB0, RB2, and RB3, and only turn on RB1? Then can you tell the difference between SW00 and SW04?

Comment: @Sneftel, I did, i.e. made RB0 input to disable it, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @Sneftel, or I must disable also RB2,RB3?

Comment: @Sneftel, you helped me greatly, thanks to you!